# Moving multiple cells to a new sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the current code which works perfectly fine. This code will take the cell A1 from worksheet "update" and put it into cell A2 of worksheet "Archived.

```
Worksheets("Archived").Range("A2") = Worksheets("Update").Range("Table2").Range("A1")
```

However, when I do multiple cells at once, it does not work. It simply does not copy nothing into any cells within worksheet "Archived". Why is this?

```
Worksheets("Archived").Range("A2:A3") = Worksheets("Update").Range("Table2").Range("A1:A2")
```

I have used the .copy method before but heard it is slower and semi-efficient & that this would be a better route to take. Is this true?

Comment: Try putting `.Value` after each range.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I have added this. Thank you.

Comment: @ScottCraner This has fixed my issue. Why is it that not having ".Value" worked for a single ranged cell, while ".Value" is needed for a multiple cell range?

Comment: As to the `Why?` I am not sure, and there are those smarter than me that may know, but I guess it has to do with the fact that you are converting it to an array and when doing so vba needs to know what it is converting, ie values,formula,... just a stab in the dark.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look into that a bit more. Can you please place your comment in a form of an answer so I can reward you? -Thanks!

Comment: As my comment fixed the issue but did not answer the question I will leave it as a comment in hopes that someone who knows the `Why?` part can answer.  Glad I could help with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer not to work with ranges of cells. You could do

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Archived").Cells(2, 1).FormulaR1C1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Update").Cells(1, 1).Value
```

for copy one single cell or

```
For x = 1 To 2
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Archived").Cells(x + 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Update").Cells(x, 1).Value
Next x
```

for copy multiple adjacent cells.